# How can AM modulation be performed in LTspice by built in MODULATOR function?

Tags: ltspice

I have been looking for this for an hour and there is no single example or information about it in English language. The nearest ones are like [this](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/08/e0/80/08e080326bab25fac422a3b3941270fb.jpg) and there is no explanation I don't even know it is correct. No tutorial, no example, no diagram ect.

I used search still no luck:

https://www.google.com/search?biw=1422&bih=655&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=kV0EW7fHG8OwsAGa7YyYCg&q=am+modulation+ltspice&oq=am+modulation+ltspice&gs_l=img.3...151628.151628.0.151831.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.img..0.0.0....0.EcFpzqH5i3c

As an example how can we modulate a 1k carrier signal with a 10Hz signal by using the the built-in MODULATOR? (AM not FM)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the help:

> The MODULATE device is a voltage controlled oscillator. See the
>   example schematic .\examples\Educational\PLL.asc. The instantaneous
>   oscillation frequency is set by the voltage on the FM input. The
>   conversion from voltage to frequency is linear and set by the two
>   instance parameters, mark and space. Mark is the frequency when the FM
>   input is at 1V and space is the frequency when the input is at 0V. The
>   amplitude is set by the voltage on the AM input and defaults to 1V if
>   that input is unused(connected to the MODULATE common).

So you place that component, connect the bottom port to GND, and write the frequencies you want into the `Value` part in the format of `mark=xyz space=abc` mark will be the frequency when 1 V is supplied to FM and space the one when 0 V is supplied.

At the AM port you just put some sine or whatever:

[image: Working example of the modulator]

Comment: @user16307 That's exactly what I told you, in [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77862/discussion-between-a-concerned-citizen-and-user16307), isn't it?

Answer (score 4):

Just use something like this: -

[image]

[image]

Comment: But I want to learn to use the built-in MODULATOR which is claimed to be faster.

Comment: Something like this with english explanation: http://www.auldies.euweb.cz/me/m10_AMmod_mod.jpg

Comment: I don't see any reason why a text line that defines a source that is as simple as V(Vc)*V(Vm) can be improved upon in speed.

Comment: Show your failed implementation in your question please.

Comment: I have no idea how to implement it, but this one was what i tried: https://i.imgur.com/yjsqeei.png There is no source how to do it in english. Ive been looking for an hour, nothing. I also asked if someone else might encounter the answer one day in search.