# Enveloping curve - LTspice

Tags: ltspice, passive-networks

I have built a simple RLC circuit with a pulse input and performing transient analysis on it. I am interested in the voltage of the behavioral voltage source as shown in circuit.

[image]

The system is an under-damped system so the voltage at the behavioral voltage  node is an under-damped signal.

[image]

I want to plot the enveloping curve for the same.

Answer (score 1):

Then run that signal through a rectifier, or even better a precision rectifier:

[image]
Source: https://www.electronics-tutorial.net/analog-integrated-circuits/precision-rectifier/precision-full-wave-rectifier/

Then put a low pass filter on the output (vo) with a pole that is lower than the frequency of the envelope. You may also want to put a voltage buffer/follower between Vin of the precision wave and the voltage point that you want to measure the envelope.

OR

Use the [AM modulator](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/375803/how-can-am-modulation-be-performed-in-ltspice-by-built-in-modulator-function) that is built into LT spice